# Estou achando muito complicado ajeitar o layout no xml

Tags: android

Quero fazer um menu simples. Mas ele fica todo torto poxa o que faço?Alguém me dá dicas? Sou nova no android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="projeto.ba.gr.noamobile.MenuActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_menu"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="50">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAlerta"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TESTE"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/aviso"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnNoaCidadao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TESTE"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/aviso"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOperacao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TESTE"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/aviso"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMul"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TESTE"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/aviso"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Adiciona uma foto do que você está tentando construir, ou uma descrição melhor, "um menu" é muito amplo. Seria legal uma foto de como está o seu projeto atualmente, pra entendermos o que é "torto"

Comment: De repente o LinearLayout não seja o que você precisa, tente outros, como o Relative ou Frame

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAlerta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TESTE"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNoaCidadao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TESTE"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOperacao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TESTE"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/aviso"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMul"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TESTE"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/aviso"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Arrumei o seu layout.
o "peso" (weight) esta vem 50, mudei os dois para 1, assim fica 50% mais simples.

Havia valores layout_margins também.

Acredito que assim resolva.